# socket io - Emit an event every X seconds or just emit it after a POST event?

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I'm using socket io, and I was wondering what was better.

Emiting an event every X seconds to keep always updated with the database or emit the event after e.g a POST event, so it's more efficient.

I believe updating X seconds should be easier, and maybe has better scalability, but don't know if that's the correct way.

EDIT-1: To give more context. The application is for an accounting team. They basically want their excel sheets converted to a app. They have a lot of data, so I don't know if emitting an event every X seconds is a good idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "correct" way.  It depends entirely upon the needs of your client and the capabilities of your server.  If the client needs to be kept more instantly up-to-date, then send data from your server to the client whenever the server has new data.  If the client only needs to be updated every once-in-a-while, then only send it data every once-in-a-while.  There is no "correct" way.  It depends upon your application.

It is always more efficient to only send data to the client when the data has actually changed and when the client actually cares that something has changed.  So, it would be foolish to send a client update every few seconds if the data isn't actually changing that often.  If you have a means of knowing when the data changes on the server, then use that event to know when to send data to the client and even then, don't send it more often than the client actually cares to know.

It is always more efficient to have the server do no more work than is actually required by the client.  Things like caching and keeping track of what each client was last sent can sometimes save lots of work for the server too.

Any further advice on this matter would need to know a lot more about the needs of your application and how this particular data fits into that and how often the data in question actually changes.

A summary on this topic:

- Send data to the client no more often than it needs it
- Sending data to the client that has not changed since the last time you changed it is inefficient for the server and consumes bandwidth.
- Only you can decide how often your client needs updates (it depends upon your application)
- Only you can test the impact on scalability of sending data to every client every time the data changes.
- Server-side caching and keeping track of what client already has what data can help you avoid sending data to a client that it already has.
- Server-side scalability probably has a lot to do with how many simultaneous clients are connected and how frequently there is changed data to send them.

Comment: My application is about accounting data. For example keep the list of companies they work for in real time. They are a small accounting team so I think server load wouldn't be a problem

Comment: @LucasGomes - Does this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.  If not, then please indicate what is not yet answered.